# REST API - ALPS UI (Swagger UI like)

Tags: rest, documentation, swagger, spring-data-rest

I am evaluating [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) at the moment and I really like it.

What I am missing is a nicely presented, **interactive** documentation possibility similar to [Swagger UI](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/).

I know that Spring Data REST is not a static API and that there is [HAL Browser](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_hal_browser), but unfortunately the HAL Browser does **not show any documentational metadata** about the corresponding url/GET/POST/etc.

Spring Data REST produces [ALPS](http://alps.io/spec/) metadata (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.alps)).

---

**Why is this needed?**
Well, it would be pretty useful for frontend developers and increase productivity from my point of view. Additionally every kind of auto-generated documentation saves a lot of time.

---

**Long story short:**
Is there something like "***Swagger UI for ALPS/Hypermedia aware REST APIs***"?

---

**Additional information:**
I already found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389733/document-hal-links-from-spring-hateoas-with-swagger) that describes the problem, but I wasn't sure if its ok to reraise it, so I created this new one. Maybe in the meantime there are possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Put [this](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser) in your dependencies and smoke it:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

referenced at: /api/browser

I was just looking for the same thing today. ALPS is the metadata -- but SRD produces hal -- all you need is something to navigate HAL data and you're done.

Comment: Nice. But it seems to run on the real data. How does it deal with authentication? (OAuth Bearer token)